# Typescript is invalid

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I upgraded angular to 4 and angular cli to 1.03.
After I run the command `npm ls typescript` I get:

```
+-- @angular/cli@1.0.3
| `-- typescript@2.2.2
`-- typescript@2.2.2  invalid

npm ERR! invalid: typescript@2.2.2 C:\development\projects-git\mydoc\static-web\node_modules\typescript
```

What's the difference between the first and the second typescript, why is the second one invalid/how do I fix it?

I think the error above is the reason why I get the error below so I hope there is a fix for both so I can run my application again.

```
ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (..\static-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:9580:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (..\static-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:66674:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (..\static-web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:202:31)
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue where i even had two different typescript versions listed when i did `npm ls typescript`.

> What's the difference between the first and the second typescript

The first one is listed as a dependency of `@angular/cli`, the second one is a dependency of your own project.

> why is the second one invalid/how do I fix it?

In my case, i had `typescript` defined under both, `dependencies` and `devDependencies` section in my `package.json`.
I removed it from `dependencies` and the duplicate output disappeared.

Comment: Thanks already did that by now but it seems that it wasn't the origin of the error.

Comment: Instead of upgrading your cli-project, you could try to generate a new one with `ng new new-project`, copy your `src` folder (and `package.json` deps) over and try whether your error persists. If not, take the newly generated configuration files over into your existing project. This solution is easier on smaller projects without lots of customizations, but it may be worth a try even for a more complex scenario.